# Efficient way to loop letters through 7-seg LEDs

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to scroll through the words 'Happy Bday' on four 7-seg LEDs on my FPGA board. On each cycle, the words would move left by one letter. I've been able to do this so far by defining a state for each combination and just cycling through the states. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, since if I ever wanted to scroll through many more words, I would have to have a lot of states.

```
module bday (
    input rst_b, clk, start,
    output logic [6:0] led [3:0]
);
    logic clk_d;
    logic [25:0] count;
    state_t state; // state enum

    always @(posedge clk) begin
       count <= count + 1;
       if (count == 10000000)
       begin
          count <= '0;
          clk_d <= !clk_d; // divide clock down from 50MHz source
       end
    end

    always_ff @ (posedge clk_d, negedge rst_b)
    begin
        if (!rst_b)
        begin
            state <= S_idle;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) led[i] <= '1;
        end
        else // letters below are 7-bit parameters to light up the 7-seg LED correctly
            case (state)
                S_idle : if (start) state <= S_1; else state <= S_idle;
                S_1 : begin state <= S_2; led[0] = H; led[1] = A; led[2] = P; led[3] = P; end
                S_2 : begin state <= S_3; led[0] = A; led[1] = P; led[2] = P; led[3] = Y; end
                S_3 : begin state <= S_4; led[0] = P; led[1] = P; led[2] = Y; led[3] = BLANK; end 
                S_4 : begin state <= S_5; led[0] = P; led[1] = Y; led[2] = BLANK; led[3] = B; end
                S_5 : begin state <= S_6; led[0] = Y; led[1] = BLANK; led[2] = B; led[3] = D; end
                S_6 : begin state <= S_7; led[0] = BLANK; led[1] = B; led[2] = D; led[3] = A; end
                S_7 : begin state <= S_8; led[0] = B; led[1] = D; led[2] = A; led[3] = Y; end
                S_8 : begin state <= S_9; led[0] = D; led[1] = A; led[2] = Y; led[3] = BLANK; end
                S_9 : begin state <= S_10; led[0] = A; led[1] = Y; led[2] = BLANK; led[3] = H; end
                S_10 : begin state <= S_11; led[0] = Y; led[1] = BLANK; led[2] = H; led[3] = A; end
                S_11 : begin state <= S_1; led[0] = BLANK; led[1] = H; led[2] = A; led[3] = P; end
                default : state <= S_idle;
            endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things you can do.

Separate the scrolling behavior from the message you want to display

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk_d, negedge rst_b)
        if (!rst_b)
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) led[i] <= '1;
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) led[i] <= led[i+1];
```

Then use an array and a counter to pick the letters from your message

```
parameter logic [6:0] message[15] = {H,A,P,P,Y,BLANK,B,I,R,T,H,D,A,Y,BLANK};
logic [7:0] counter;
always_ff @ (posedge clk_d, negedge rst_b)
        if (!rst_b)
        begin
            counter <=0;
            led[3] <= '1;
        end
        else
            led[3] <= message[counter];
            if (counter < 15) 
               counter <= counter+1;
            else
               counter <= 0;
```

Comment: This worked. The only thing I had to do was explicitly make `message` unpacked: `{H,A,P,P,Y,BLANK,B,I,R,T,H,D,A,Y,BLANK}`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would use is to make a "ROM". You can make a synchronous, or an  asynchronous one.

```
module async_rom64(
   input logic [5:0] address,
   output logic [6:0] led [3:0]
);
    always @( * ) 
       case (address)
       6'd0 : {led[0] , led[1] , led[2] , led[3] } = {H,A,p,P};
       6'd1 : {led[0] , led[1] , led[2] , led[3] } = {A,P,P,Y};
       6'd2 : {led[0] , led[1] , led[2] , led[3] } = {P,P,Y,BLANK};
       // ...
       // 6'd63 : ...
       endcase

endmodule
```

Now you just change the address of the ROM and a new set of LED patterns come out.

From here you can make it as complex as you want.

- For example you can add a 'last' bit which tells the address counter that it has to start counting from zero again.
- You can add a delay per state.
- You add a repeat field to e.g. repeat a pattern and then go to the next.